# How to align `button-group` horizontal in the centre of the column div?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, alignment

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <ul class="button-group ">
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">3 months</a></li>
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">6 months</a></li>
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">9 months</a></li>
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">1 year</a></li>
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">2 years</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add `text-center` to the `ul` and also `large-centered` to the column without success.

I believe there is a class in `foundation` to centre the group of buttons, but I could not find it.

http://jsfiddle.net/vZdbY/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the `ul` fit to the `li`'s using `display: inline-block` and then give `text-align: center` to the parent element of the `ul` tag.

```
.large-12.columns {  /* applies to the div which has the both classes */
    text-align: center;
}

ul.button-group{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vZdbY/9/)

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZdbY/3/)** (*using display: inline-block to `li`'s*)

Comment: `inline-block` was going to be my suggestion as well. You also should consider adding `margin-right: -0.36em` to the `li` elements. This is because `inline-block` treats the items as text, and as such adds white space around them. The negative margin trick is generally effective cross-browser in eliminating unwanted spacing. There are other methods involving letter spacing and word spacing, but those have issues in different browsers.

Comment: @aaronburrows yes there is space which can be removed by using many methods like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZdbY/8/). but I am sure that the OP is unaware of the default font-size though.

Comment: I stay away from the `font-size: 0` method because it breaks relative font sizing. If you're using em sizes and then you set the ul to 0, you then have to use pixels to make text visible again.

Comment: this solution will mess up my whole application. I'm using `foundation 4` and I have a lot of rows and columns in my application.

Comment: @gabrielhilal I have no knowledge of foundation 4. Can you create a simple fiddle which illustrates what do you mean by "_mess_"?

Comment: `foundation 4` is similar to `twitter bootstrap`... a framework for front end that provides a lot of classes including `row`, `columns`, `large-XX` for the grid system. So, I can't change the classes, otherwise it will affect the entitle application. Anyway, I solved the problem based on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to register here in case someone else is facing the problem...

Based on @Mr_Green answer, I solved the problem adding `display: inline-block` to the `ul` with a new css class, avoiding that changes to affect the use of `button-group` in other parts of my application.

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 text-center columns">
    <ul class="button-group fix_button_group">
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">3 months</a></li>
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">6 months</a></li>
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">9 months</a></li>
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">1 year</a></li>
      <li><a class="tiny secondary button" href="#">2 years</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fix_button_group{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: yeah I was unaware of that the class was being added by foundation though.